# FCPX ken burns zoom in and out

Tags: final-cut-pro, final-cut-pro-x

How can i apply ken burns to zoom in and out ? it can only either zoom in or out then move to the second clip

I want to zoom into specific target then zoom back in to make it fit to the next clip